# Will Neural Network translate to the same sentence in different runtimes? And can I receive many translated sentences at a runtime?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, translation, recurrent-neural-network

I intend to use Neural Network (CNN, RNN, etc) to translate from a language to another one in a sentence unit. I wonder that this network will give us the same sentence in different runtimes or not. And can we have many translated sentences at a runtime?

Supposed we have these scenarios:

```
Runtime 1: sentence --- a
Runtime 2: sentence --- a
Runtime 3: sentence --- b
Runtime 4: sentence --- a, b, c, etc
```

Which scenarios does NW will give us? Thank!

Comment: Those two questions are interesting and deserve two dedicated answers. For next time I recommend you to keep one question per post if those questions are not closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two identical neural networks (same architecture and same weights), then inference is deterministic: two identical inputs will give the same output. That wouldn't be true if you used some kind of randomness inside the archicture of your neural networks, for example if you used a [Variational Autoencoder (VAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), or a [Generative Adversarial Network (GAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network), as you would be learning and sampling statistical distributions.

For your second question: neural networks take tensors as input, and provide tensors as output. The input can a 1D tensor (vector), 2D tensor (matrix), or even a 666D tensor (although it is not recommended). In the end, inference with neural networks is just a series of tensor product.

When you study linear algebra, you learn that in a product of tensors you can always stack one of the tensor with itself (or with a different one of same size) alongside a specific dimension and the expression will remain correct. So if you stack your input tensors correctly (one-hot encoding of your sentences I guess), you can run your prediction as a **batch**. In this case your output tensors (one-hot encoding of your translated sentences) will also be stacked together. But be aware that (1) such batch should fit in memory, and (2) the larger the batch the more computation it will take.

Answer (score 0):

yes, as long as you have 2 different neural networks. I am not an expert in this at the same time though because I have only done it once.